# ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror

For some reason I receive an `ImportError` every time I try to import a class from another file. Here's the github page for my project: https://github.com/wheelebin/mcnextbot

Here's the error that I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ircbot.py", line 36, in <module>
    from test import mcnextlvl
ImportError: cannot import name mcnextlvl
```

Comment: `from lib.test import mcnextlvl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your `from test import something` refers to the module `test` in `<PYTHONPATH>/lib`, not yourselves `test.py`, and there is no submodule/class `mcnextlvl` there. You should use `from lib.test import mcnextlvl` as @sgmart commented.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__.py` python file allow you can import your individual modules named 'test' from the lib package.